# ASP.NET MVC Is it possible to have image version like javascript version?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, image

all.
I want to version image on site.
Example for usage is next: my site have some image (e.g. search bar background 190px width). When I changed background image, I saved it with same file name). After that, I accessed page, but old image was displayed and page design crashed. I could see good image with only ctrl+f5.

Is there any kind of image version algorithm similar u js versioning?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard technique for cache busting is to change the URI by adding or modifying the query string. There is nothing language specific about that.

If you are modifying a background image that is a standard part of the design, then you should be just editing your CSS to change the URI. Neither ASP.NET nor JS needs to be involved.

Comment: I assumed that it might be like that, which is same idea that we had in mind. Thanks a lot.